# What encoding does Javascript fs.readFileSync return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, buffer, readfile

Consider the following Node.js Javascript program:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var encoding1='?';
var encoding2='?';
var a = fs.readFileSync('./testdoc.pdf');
var b = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('./testdoc.pdf',encoding1),encoding2);
console.log(a===b);
```

To what values must the **encoding1** and **encoding2** variables be set in order for *true* to be printed at the console?

Comment: "Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons.", "An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object." -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

Answer (score 5):

### You need `a.equals(b)`

For binary data like PDF you should use the `"binary"` encoding but no encoding will make any two buffers equal with the `===` operator so `a === b` will always give you `false`. You need to use `a.equals(b)` to test if two buffers have the same contents.

See `buf.equals(otherBuffer)` in the docs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_equals_otherbuffer

### Example

See this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var encoding1 = 'binary';
var encoding2 = 'binary';
var a = fs.readFileSync('./testdoc.pdf');
var b = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('./testdoc.pdf', encoding1), encoding2);
console.log('Object equality:', a === b);
console.log('Buffer equality:', a.equals(b));
```

It will print:

```
Object equality: false
Buffer equality: true
```