# "Can't embed page with missing Contents" with pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting a "**Can't embed page with missing Contents**" error, from the `pdfDoc.save()` command at the end of creating pdf document, using "pdf-lib".
I noticed that if I delete the line: `this.doc.embedPdf(fileBuffer)`, previously written in the code - the error doesn't pop, but also of course, doesn't embed a PDF document I loaded.
Any ideas?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');

// ...

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

// ...

const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/${pdfFileName}.pdf`);
const embeddedPdf = await pdfDoc.embedPdf(fileBuffer);
const page = this.addNewPage();
page.drawPage(pdfPage);

// ...

try {
    await pdf.doc.save();
} catch(err) {
   // thats where the error hits
}
```

while debugging the code, all of the variables (fileBuffer, embeddedPdf, page) seems legit.

Comment: It feels like `fileBuffer` may be undefined... I think you can't expect any more detailled answer since there is absolutely no code in that question. Please have a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it's not undefined, ill add the code ASAP :)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855288/what-encoding-does-javascript-fs-readfilesync-return)... That seems to be the issue (about the encoding).

Comment: Apparently it was because the library can't handle an empty PDF.

Comment: Curiosity... What is an empty PDF? A white page saved as PDF?

Comment: exactly that. a PDF without any "content".

Comment: So what is `fileBuffer` in this case? An empty string or `undefined`? Based on what this case returns to `fileBuffer`, I would add a condition to avoid the error.

Comment: it's a regular valid buffer, full with data. I cant also open the file itself and see it has meta data and such, but just a blank page in it. you can think about it as "the document doesn't have any nodes in it"

Comment: Hey... I just found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse) while searching how to read a PDF to ensure it is not blank... It seems `data.text` can be read... ;) -- It is the best I can do to help. I will look forward to see your solution posted!